# Flutter Android Studio Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.0.1 error

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, androidx

After updating Flutter and a few packages I'm consistently getting the

> Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.0.1 error

I've migrated my project to Android X and gradle build 28, but the error will not clear.  Please help.  Here is a snippet of my `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mycompany"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this one: `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0`

Look here for more: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.0.1 error

It happens because **androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.0.1** doesn't exist.

You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions) and the release notes of [legacy-support package](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/legacy).

**Use:**

```
api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

You can also check the [google maven repo](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html). Here the list of available releases:

```
1.0.0-alpha1
1.0.0-alpha3
1.0.0-beta01
1.0.0-rc01
1.0.0-rc02
1.0.0
```